# Как нарисовать 3D линию?

Tags: c++, 3d

Поставлю вопрос по другому. Мне нужно нарисовать 3D линию используя стандартные средства `VS c++ 2012` (никаких `opengl` и т.д).
В общем я нашел, что существует библиотека `windows.h`, с помощью которой можно рисовать. Но там только 2D линии. А мене нужно 3D.
В общем помогите с помощью `windows.h` реализовать функцию типа `drawLine(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)`. Буду благодарен!

Comment: Нарисовать тень, а на ней линию. Либо как в школе на уроках геометрии объемные фигуры рисовали также линиями нарисовать и тут. Это должна быть статика?

Comment: а что такое 3D-линия? Линия вообще объект одномерный (даже не двумерный), поскольку имеет только одно измерение

Comment: все не так просто. Нарисовать тень в консоли невозможно. На уроках геометрии на листку нарисовать просто, а вот программно нет. Я просто не представляю себе как организовать ось y (коротая надает объема)

Comment: @DreamChild, плоскость XYZ

Comment: Нарисовать тень легко. Надо нарисовать сначала черную линию, затем повторить со смещением цветную и все. И с помощью WinApi можно создать окно и в нем нарисовать.

Comment: @miyu: А как вы собираетесь рисовать двухмерную линию на трёхмерном экране? Если Вы хотите нарисовать её _проекцию_, по подсчитайте проекции концов линии, и соедините их обыкновенной двумерной линией.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток!

Сразу оговорюсь, что задача перед Вами не из простых и кода я здесь Вам представить не смогу, хотя бы из тех соображений что места на него не хватит)).

Сперва необходимо вспомнить аналитическую геометрию: матрицы и вектора и все операции с ними. Далее реализовать эти абстракции в коде. Используя написанное реализовать рисование будет проще.

В заключении самое главное: [здесь](http://www.sciyouth.ru/ElBibl/Komppjuterja%20geometrija%20i%20grafika/%D0%95.%D0%92.%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD,%20%D0%90.%D0%92.%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2.%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0.%20%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0,%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0.pdf) книга, которая помогла мне в свое время разобраться (хоть это было и не просто). В ней содержится решение Вашей задачи, однако от Вас потребуется отфильтровать нужное и приспособить приведенный в книге код под конкретные библиотеки которыми вы пользуетесь (древний VGA, или Borland C++ или MFC и т.п.) и Ваши потребности.

Желаю успехов!

Comment: Ну, зачем так сложно, целая книга.

Проекция точки `P(x, y, z)` на плоскость, заданную точкой `P0(x0, y0, z0)` и нормальным единичным вектором `n(nx, ny, nz)`, считается в векторной форме

    X - n ((X - X0)*n)

(очевидно) или в скалярной

    (x - k * nx, y - k * ny, z - k * nz)

где `k = (X - X0)*n = (x - x0) * nx + (y - y0) * ny + (z - z0) * nz`.

Comment: @VladD, только вот без источника света и других (кроме этой линии) объектов сцены никакой 3-мерности на экране видно не будет.

Comment: @avp: Я вот буквально 2 часа назад рисовал проекции трёхмерных wireframe-ов на экране, без всякого источника света. Фигура растеризуется в отрезки, концы проектируются на плоскость экрана и соединяются отрезком на экране, всё.